# Blender cloth animation isn't working properly?

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, transforms, cloth-simulation

I am using Blender 2.8 and I have been trying to make a realistic-looking fabric on my bowl. But it is starting animation early and becoming something like in the photo. I have tried it on a cube to look if the problem is on collision or cloth physics, but I think the problem is cloth physics. I have tried to making origin at the center or bottom or top, but nothing changed. Please help me.[image]

Comment: That looks similar to the problem described here : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/186520/29586. Ensure to Apply Scale and check your self-collision to ensure the range isn’t set too high.

Comment: this helped me thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you hit the self collision check box in the cloth modifier setting as and keep the quality steps high to get a good cloth simulation(The more the quality step the better the quality and slower rendering).

[image: Cloth]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I checked self-collision, but it is still the same.