# Cloth simulation glitch

Tags: cloth-simulation

Im trying to run a simple cloth simulation in 2.83 but the result is like scrutched up and looks terrible, also it takes like 15 minutes to bake 60 frames. I don't know if it's because of the sewing force or self collision. If anyone can help me, I'd be grateful!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add more info? What is the expected result? What is this? ;-) It's hard to tell from the image. Do you use a pin group? Sewing? What are the settings? Mesh density and collision settings are imported, too. You can share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Looks to me the same as https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/186520/29586 due to self-collision. I can't mark it as a duplicate since the related answer doesn't have any upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer copied from [Self Collision - Blender Cloth Sim shrinks mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/186520/29586) as can't flag as duplicate since it has no upvotes...)

Most likely your cloth vertices are self-colliding with their neighbours due to the Self Collision Distance being too large.

Firstly, when running a simulation always ensure the meshes are created at 'real world' scales - eg, for a bedsheet you might assume 2 metres a side (or 2 Blender Units). Ensure you Ctrl+A and 'Apply Scale' following any changes to scale - to ensure the simulation is using the correct scale.

Secondly, reduce the Self Collisions 'Distance' property. At Blender 2.83.2 this defaults to 0.015 metres (1.5cm). If your vertices are closer together you may want to reduce that value.